# Is arr.length=0 better than arr=[] in javascript while reseting

Tags: javascript

I'm improving the performance of a HTML5 Game,while I reset some arrays,in order to reduce the  garbage collection,I tend to use array.length=0(Yet I'm not sure if it's working in real world)
I did some tests to find out the speed of these 2 types of reset array here
http://tinkerbin.com/hqQvp5fQ

Comment: have you tried http://jsperf.com/?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, setting `length` to zero is a better solution since it truncates an existing array while `arr=[]` creates a new array and stores a reference to it in `arr`. It may happen that the old array isn't referenced any more and will be garbage collected. Hence, `arr=[]` may require an extra allocation and garbage collection compared to `arr.length=0`.

See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) for the description of the special behavior of the `length` property on which this relies.